# Query mongo collection using Python dict

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My MongoDB documents look like:

```
{
  'x': 1,
  'y': 2,
  'z': 3
},
{
  'x': 10,
  'y': 20,
  'z': 30
},
{
  'x': 100,
  'y': 200,
  'z': 300
},
```

and the queries look like:

```
query_1 = {
  'x': [1, 100]
}

query_2 = {
'x': [10],
'z': [2]
}
```

Unfortunately, when we do `collection.find(query_1)` or `collection.find(query_2)`, we get no results which is because of the lists in the queries. How can I make Mongo take my queries? Please note that the 'values' of my query dictionaries are always lists.

**EDIT:**

Expanding on Belly Buster's answer below, I believe if I do:

```
{
'$or': [
         {'x': {'$in': ['item1', 'item2']}},
         {'y': {'$in': ['item1', 'item2']}}
        ]
}
```

answers my question. However, I feel that there is a better way to achieve this. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 1 you are searching on a field `x` that contains a list `[1, 100]`. As there aren't any records matching, you get no results. Now if you wanted to search `x` for either 1 or 100, you need to use the `$in` operator; your query should be:

```
result = db.mycollection.find({'x': {'$in': [1, 100]}})
```

Query 2 you are searching on a field `x` containing a list `[10]` and a field `z` containing a list `[2]`. Again there's nothing matching that in your data.

I'm not sure what query you are trying to perform for this, but if it is `x == 10 or z == 2`, then your query is :

```
result = db.mycollection.find({'$or': [{'x': 10}, {'z': 2}]})
```

Comment: In other words, imagine that my documents contain many more fields and each field contains a list of items. I would like to be able to write a query that searches for a subset of fields and a subset of items of each field. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I believe I figured it out: query = {
    '$or': [{'x': {'$in': ['item1', 'item2']}},
              {'y': {'$in': ['item1', 'item2']}}]
}. I'm hoping that there is an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: That's exactly how you do it, and no, there's no "easier" way. That is the way!

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept your answer as it pointed me in the right direction.